# Form of the Wronskian in the Legendre operator $Lu=(1-x^2)u''-2xu'+\nu (\nu+1)u$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

:)

The question was in two parts, just having problems with the second half.

Part 1: Consider a second-order, linear differential operator $Lu=a_2u''-a_1u'+a_0u$. Prove that if $Lu_1=0=Lu_2$ then the Wronskian $$W=\left\vert \begin{array}{c c} u_1 & u_1' \\ u_2 & u_2' \end{array}\right\vert$$ satisfies $a_2W'+a_1W=0$.

Part 2: Hence find the form of the Wronskian in the case of the Legendre oeprator, $$Lu=(1-x^2)u''-2xu'+\nu (\nu+1)u.$$

To be honest, I'm not really sure how to get a Wronskian. Our professor has just sort of said "this is a Wronskian, let's move on" and since then I've been trying to figure it out without much success. If anyone could even point me towards a useful definition of the Wronskian I would be very greatful. :)

Comment: The definition of the Wronskian (for two functions) is right there in the question. Use the fact that $a_2 W'+a_1 W=0$ and solve the resulting DE.

Comment: @wj32: Oh wait, I see what you mean. You mean that I should solve the ODE $(1-x^2)W'-2xW=0$ to find the Wronskian, right?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$